# Search multiple free form texts to

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2010. I have a DB that records free-form text for errors in processes. I'd like to create a function that searches the free-form texts for key-words and reports back according error codes. Not sure how to go about doing this though:

EX:
**ID** | **Desc**
1 | loose part
2 |  smeared paint
3 |  no bolts

compares to keywords in another table

**keywords**  |  **error code**
paint | 32
bolt | 25 
part | 55

And the output would look like

**ID** | **error code** 
1 | 55 
2 | 32 
3 | 25

The idea is that I can update the keywords table to include new keywords and error codes as more popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you a possible solution:

Let's assume that your tables are named tbDescriptions, tbKeywords, tbErrors.
The ID Field of tbErrors is autonumbering (if not you have just to add the ID value during rebuilding).

Here is a sub that you can use to rebuild your error table.
Please note that I assume that tbErrors can be deleted and rebuild each time you need to update it. If not so you need to manage the presence of Error in tbErrors but it's not much more complicated.

```
Private Sub RebuildErrorTable()
    Dim rsKeyWords As dao.Recordset, rsErrors As dao.Recordset
    Dim strKeyword As String
    Dim strSELECT As String
    Dim strWhereCond As String
    Dim intNumOccurrences As Integer

    '
    ' Delete all records from tbErrors
    '
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL = "DELETE * FROM tbErrors"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    '
    ' Rebuild table tbErrors
    '
    strSELECT = "SELECT * FROM tbKeyWords"
    Set rsKeyWords = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSELECT, dbOpenDynaset)      ' Open keywords table
    strSELECT = "SELECT * FROM tbErrors"
    Set rsErrors = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSELECT, dbOpenDynaset)        ' Open Errors table for rebuilding

    '
    ' Scan all keywords
    '
    Do While Not rsKeyWords.EOF

        strKeyword = rsKeyWords!keywords                                    ' Current keyword

        strWhereCond = "Desc LIKE '*" + strKeyword + "*'"                   ' Build search condition
        intNumOccurrences = DCount("ID", "tbDescriptions", strWhereCond)    ' Count keyword occurences in the descriptions table

        If intNumOccurrences > 0 Then                                       ' If keyword was found at least once
            With rsErrors                                                   ' Inser error code into Errors table
                .AddNew
                .Fields("ErrorCode") = rsKeyWords!ErrorCode
                .Update
            End With

        End If

        rsKeyWords.MoveNext                                                 ' Move to next keyword

    Loop

    '
    ' Close all and free memory
    '
    rsErrors.Close

    rsKeyWords.Close

    Set rsErrors = Nothing

    Set rsKeyWords = Nothing


End Sub
```

Bye:-)
Wiz